# write a windbg sript for a table of linkedlist

Tags: windbg, script

I'm writing a script for an array of LIST_ENTRY. Each LIST_ENTRY is a header of linkedlist.
From reference, I can use `!list` to perform the same operation for each element in the linkedlist.

`0:000> !list -t MYTYPE.links.Flink -x "dd" -a "L2" 0x6bc00`

However, this command only serves one header. How to do it with the whole array. The start value stores at rcx

```
$$ bp kernel!Func_name "$><d:\\script\\Func_name_x64.txt"

.catch
{

}
```

To be more specific, I can execute a list of LIST_ENTRY like @blabb did but what I have right now is a table of them and I want to do it repeatedly by script. The data structure looks like this. There is an array of LIST_ENTRY and each one of them is the header of its own list. The element in the list is a structure(file!typename) that contains LIST_ENTRY.

```
        file!typename
       __________   
____   |  ____  |  ____  ____
|_0_|--|->|__|--|->|__|->|__|
  |    |________| 
____   ___ 
|_1_|->|__|
```

I want to print one of the elements(A) in the structure and output in external file. Like this

```
____    
|_0_|->A1-->A2
  |
____   
|_1_|->A3
```

This operation is complicated so I think it can't be realized in one command. But I haven't used windbg script before. The windbg script resource I found doesn't have something like 'specify which element in the struct,output them to external file, and walk through the whole array'

Comment: what you have posted here is a verbatim copy of the document that describes this function have you actually tried it do you have a proof of what you are describing  i would suggest you to try and post the actual failure or result instead of presumptions

Answer (score 1):

it seems to work as documented

dumping the _LIST_ENTRY entries to a maxCount of 100 and size of 1 (only Flinks)

```
0:000> dl @@c++(&@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList) 100 1
00007ff8`5177c4d0  000001bc`43082b70
000001bc`43082b70  000001bc`430829a0
000001bc`430829a0  000001bc`430830c0
000001bc`430830c0  000001bc`430837a0
000001bc`430837a0  000001bc`43084f20
000001bc`43084f20  000001bc`430857c0
000001bc`430857c0  000001bc`430868e0
000001bc`430868e0  000001bc`43086d10
000001bc`43086d10  000001bc`43087500
000001bc`43087500  000001bc`430871d0
000001bc`430871d0  000001bc`430880a0
000001bc`430880a0  000001bc`43087a40
000001bc`43087a40  000001bc`43088bd0
000001bc`43088bd0  000001bc`43087dc0
000001bc`43087dc0  000001bc`430892c0
000001bc`430892c0  00007ff8`5177c4d0
```

executing a command for each entries of _LIST_ENTRY

```
0:000> !list  -t  ntdll!_PEB_LDR_DATA.InLoadOrderModuleList.Flink -x "?@$extret; dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY BaseDllName @$extret"  @@c++(&@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList)
```

result as follows

```
Evaluate expression: 140704495420624 = 00007ff8`5177c4d0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING ""

Evaluate expression: 1908090088304 = 000001bc`43082b70
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "cdb.exe"

Evaluate expression: 1908090087840 = 000001bc`430829a0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "ntdll.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090089664 = 000001bc`430830c0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "KERNEL32.DLL"

Evaluate expression: 1908090091424 = 000001bc`430837a0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "KERNELBASE.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090097440 = 000001bc`43084f20
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "msvcrt.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090099648 = 000001bc`430857c0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "dbgeng.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090104032 = 000001bc`430868e0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "ucrtbase.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090105104 = 000001bc`43086d10
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "RPCRT4.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090107136 = 000001bc`43087500
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "bcrypt.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090106320 = 000001bc`430871d0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "dbgmodel.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090110112 = 000001bc`430880a0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "OLEAUT32.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090108480 = 000001bc`43087a40
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "dbghelp.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090112976 = 000001bc`43088bd0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "msvcp_win.dll"

Evaluate expression: 1908090109376 = 000001bc`43087dc0
   +0x058 BaseDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "XmlLite.dll"
```